# Image pushed/float to the edge

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

unfortunately I have a problem moving the image to the edge of the screen.

```
<section class="hero-main">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="hero-main__container">
                <div class="hero-main__header">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br> amet amet amet</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="hero-main__text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img src="images/map-flag.png" style="margin-left: 107px" class="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The effect I want to achieve is presented in the screenshot. [image]

Unfortunately, my code does not fit the photo to the edge, if I push it it is not responsive.

Comment: Need to see your css or it's not possible to see how we can correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it will help v2:

```
<img src="images/map-flag.png" style="max-width: calc(100% - 107px); margin-left:107px; " class="" alt="">
```

or may be

```
<section class="hero-main" style="background-image: url('images/map-flag.png'); background-position: 100% 0; background-size: 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" >
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="hero-main__container">
                <div class="hero-main__header">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br> amet amet amet</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="hero-main__text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem applies to smaller screens - responsiveness.

Comment: Is it possible to see the whole example? Hard to cure in with only a picture.

Comment: Online: kurs-waluty.pl

Comment: It requires Username and Password.

Comment: Refresh, please - sorry.

Comment: Much better. Just edited the answer. The main problem may be with max-width of an image. <img src="images/map-flag.png" style="max-width: calc(100% - 107px); margin-left:107px; " class="" alt="">

Comment: Only in this case the photo is not sticky to the edge.

Comment: One more solution just added. Try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210499/discussion-between-focus-style-and-ilink).